# T4 template issue Newtonsoft.Json version

Tags: c#, t4

I am trying to get my t4 file to generate a specflow file for me but i am getting an error my i try to deserialize the object.

```
    <#@ assembly name="Newtonsoft.Json" #>
    <#@ import namespace="Newtonsoft.Json" #>

orderConfirmation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Order>(orderConfirmationJson);
```

This is the error
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

My project is referencing version 12 of Newtonsoft.Json and even when i downgrade the package it made no difference.

app.config

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I also tried importing the dll this way

```
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)\..\..\Dependencies\Packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.2\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" #>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you include how you are referencing the library in your App.config for the project?

Comment: Include it in the question

Comment: Did you install via Nuget or adding it as a reference? Worst case, grab the dll from the other computer, and the option from the App.config file and see what you can do with it.